# Convert 200+ Excel Files in a Folder into 1 Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 200+ excel workbook files in a folder with various sheets and I would like to combine them into one single excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

excelfolder = 'path to the folder'

path_names = []

for root, folder, files in os.walk(excelfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            path_names.append(filename)




writer = pd.ExcelWriter('goal.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

for x in path_names:
    for x in path_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(path_names)
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(sheet_number))

writer.save()
```

I am getting an error in my code about an invalid path file as >class list<. Does anyone see some way I could tweak my code to pass the list of path names for each workbook in the folder to combine them all into one excel workbook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

does this do what you want it to?

```py
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os

excelfolder = "path to the folder"

path_names = []

for root, folder, files in os.walk(excelfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            path_names.append(fullname)

sheet_number = 1

# originally, I thought we needed openpyxl for this but I guess could be either that or xlsxwriter
with pd.ExcelWriter("goal.xlsx", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
    wb: openpyxl.Workbook = writer.book

    for path in path_names:
        # If None is specified, all sheets are returned, as a {sheet_name: dataframe} dictionary:
        df_dict = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None)
        for sheet_name, df in df_dict.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"Sheet{sheet_number}")
            sheet_number += 1
            # or using the original sheet_name:
            # df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going through the code now and it is still running. In the end, would all the excel files condense into df_dict?

Comment: no df_dict is a dictionary of DataFrames per Excel workbook. The Excel files and their sheets go into df_dict temporarily and then we push those copies into the pd.ExcelWriter.book - i.e. the openpyxl or xlsxwriter object. Since I used a context manager it automatically saves the openpyxl or xlsxwriter object under the file name "goal.xlsx" saved in the cwd

Comment: I see, the problem is that the script is not terminating I am assuming that something strange is happening with the for loops.

Comment: did you try adding some print statements or using a tqdm progress bar? Or trying it out on a test folder with less data etc.?